# No data displayed for Device type analytics

Tags: experience-analytics

In the Experience Analytics, there is the `Device` section under the `Audience` tab which shows reports like - *Top device types by visit*, *Top device types by bounces* etc. They never showed any data. Are there any config settings to make to get these graphs to show up.

Using Sitecore 8.2 update 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup (and subscribe to) [Sitecore Device Detection](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/developing/device_detection/device_detection/set_up_device_detection).

- You must have Sitecore 8.1 or later installed. From Sitecore XP 9.0 and onwards, the Device Detection functionality is available by default without needing to purchase an additional subscription.
- To optimize access to the Device database in a scaled environment, it is best practice to store the database in a location where all of your Sitecore instances can access it. You can do this by setting the common path for each Sitecore server as shown:

`<setting name="DeviceDetection.DatabasePath" value="/App_Data/DeviceDetection" />`

- If you are running Sitecore Experience Platform 8.0, you must upgrade to the latest version to use Device Detection. The device functionality is upgraded automatically.